# C++ how to make velocity equal in all directions?

Tags: c++, sdl

I feel this is a difficult question to articulate, so I have illustrated on this graph (I am using SDL in C++).
Each square represents a pixel on the screen, I want the red pixel to move at the same speed regardless of direction.

If the speed is 8 pixels/sec then after 1 second:

- If the user input is right OR down the pixel will arrive at the position marked in blue
- If the user input is right AND down it will arrive at the position marked green.

[image: pixels]

In both cases the pixel has been displaced by 8 pixels, however.. The euclidean distance between red and blue = 8.00 and red and green = 11.31. I want the pixel to arrive at yellow instead.

So I have tried to correct this by declaring a constant speed, then I divide this by the actual displacement, giving me a number I use to multiple the X and Y coordinates and travel back along the trajectory, limiting my speed.

The code looks sorta like this (I have commented the area of interest):

```
float velX = 0, velY = 0, currentX, currentY;
int time = 0, speed = 300;

//Events
void handleInput(){
    if( event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN ){
        switch( event.key.keysym.sym ){
            case SDLK_UP: {velY -= speed;} break;
            case SDLK_DOWN: {velY += speed;} break;
            case SDLK_LEFT: {velX -= speed;} break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT: {velX += speed;} break;
        }
    }
    else if( event.type == SDL_KEYUP ){
        //do the opposite
    }
}

//Logic
void move(){

    //float dist = sqrt( (velX*velX) + (velY*velY) );
    //
    //if(dist > 0){
    //        velX *= speed / dist;
    //        velY *= speed / dist;
    //}

    currentX += velX * (get_delta_ticks(&time) / 1000.f);
    currentY += velY * (get_delta_ticks(&time) / 1000.f);
    set_delta_ticks(&time);
}

//Render
void Player::render(){
    apply_surface(currentX, currentY, spriteSheet, screen, &currentClip);
}
```

So here is my question, I am new to programming games and I'm unsure if this is the CORRECT way to be doing movement.. It seems a bit inefficient in ways, should I be trying to deduce the position based on an angle and the length of the hypotenuse instead? I don't know very much about trigonometry but of course I am keen to learn.

Comment: Divide both x and y displacements by sqrt(2)  when both buttons pressed. Should you need 3D then divide by sqrt(3) when tree buttons pressed. Of course you will floor() or ceil() the result to put in exact square point.

Comment: What types are `velX`, `velY`, `currentX`, and `currentY`?

Comment: Useful search terms: Euclidean distance, Manhattan distance, dtto for "metric" instead of "distance."

Comment: thank you for all the answers, it has been very helpful. I have updated my question.

Comment: My first thought was, if you make velocity equal in all directions, the effective velocity becomes 0.

Comment: @sehe it's a vector anyway so it would have to be velocity components equal along all axes.  0,0,0 is one solution, maybe infinity,infinity,infinity is also valid?

Answer (score 1):

Separate the logical position from the display position.

The logical position will probably need to use floating-point coordinates, and you'll round them to integer pixel coordinates for the display position. You can even do anti-aliasing with  this if you want to smooth the movement.

So:

- right would have logical unit vector `(x,y)=(1.0,0.0)`
- down would have logical unit vector `(x,y)=(0.0,-1.0)`
- down+right would have logical unit vector `(x,y)=(1/sqrt(2),-1/sqrt(2))`

every 1/8th of a second, you add the unit vector to your current logical location, and select which pixel to draw. Obviously you can choose different units and update frequencies, but this will give the numbers you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with different user controls: namely **absolute speed and direction**.

Given speed velAbs and the angle theta, you have

```
velX = velAbs * cos(theta);
velY = velAbs * sin(theta);
```

When updating the position, it is typically most convenient to decompose the absolute speed in its X and Y components, update the X and Y positions for the given time interval dt

```
currentX = velX * dt;
currentY = velY * dt;
```

whereas for collision impact computations the absolute speed is more relevant.

This will avoid your yellow/green problem because maximum throttle in both the X and Y directions will get you to green. Just let the user set the throttle from 0 to 8 and also set a direction, then you will get to yellow or blue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the speed in a 2D Space. To get it you have to do a sqrt with both speeds.

```
curSpeed = sqrt( ( velX * velX ) + (velY * velY ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is: You counted 8-x and 8-y key press events, which lead to a  shortest distance from the origin of v=sqrt(8*8+8*8)=11.31, exactly as you observed.

You should be aware, that, within the time you are measuring, either 8 (only x OR y) or 16 (x plus y) key press events might be sampled, resulting in different "speeds", where speed=number_of_key_events/period_of_time

If you want to travel to the "yellow" spot, there should be only 6 X key press events plus 6 Y key press events  in the same period of time in which you sampled the 8 key presses in one of the basic directions.

So there is nothing wrong with your code, and, as the other posters pointed out, your euclidian speed can be calculated using the euclidian distance divided by the sampling period, resulting in v=8 or v=11.31, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like most people forgot about analog input...

Anyway, It should work like this:

`velX`, `velY` are floats within [-1.0..1.0] range. 
In case of digital input (keyboard, dpad), pressing "left" sets velX to -1, pressing "right" sets velX to 1, etc.

However, if you use analog stick, you put floating point values, where `velX == 1.0` corresponds to rightmost position of analog stick, `velX == -1.0` corresponds to leftmost position, and so on.

`maxSpeed` is maximum game movement speed, also float.

With all this in mind, you could calculate next position of object like this:

```
void move(){
    float curVelX = velX, curVelY = velY;
    float moveSquared = (curVelX*curVelX + curVelY*curVelY);
    if (moveSquared > 1.0f){
         float d = sqrtf(moveSquared);
         curVelX /= d;
         curVelY /= d;
    }
    currentX += curVelX * maxSpeed * (get_delta_ticks(&time) / 1000.f);
    currentY += curVelY * maxSpeed * (get_delta_ticks(&time) / 1000.f);
    set_delta_ticks(&time);
}
```

> It seems a bit inefficient in ways,

Look, you have ONE object. When you'll have few hundreds of thousands of them, then you can start worrying about efficiency.

> should I be trying to deduce the position based on an angle and the length of the hypotenuse instead?

If your object is torpedo-like and can slowly turn left/right and accelerate/decelerate (you can steer it a bit and make it go faster/slower), then you probably need to store movement direction and linear movement speed.

If your object is some kind of flying orb or rolling ball that can go in any direction it wants, then you should use method similar to the one I described. Have separate velocity for x/y and limit maximum linear velocity using sqrtf.

Comment: ok so you have made sure moveSquared > 1.0f .. I assume this is so we never multiply the speed, but what happens when we use analogue input? If both x and y inputs are less than 0.71 the velocity will not be processed in a 2D Space?

Comment: @JoshWallace: "moveSquared > 1.0f" No I made sure that `(0 <= moveSquared <= 1)`. If moveSquared is within this range, velocity does not need to be normalized. In this case velocity will be adjusted according to user's input. IF velX is 0.1, object will move at 10% of maximum x velocity to the right. If it is -0.01, object will move at 1% of maximum velcity to the left. It won't ever exceed maximum possible speed, though.

Comment: but why does velocity not need to be normalized within that range?

Comment: @JoshWallace: Have you ever used gamepad with analog sticks? If not, you should give it a try. It works like this - if you push stick (in some direction) a little, object moves slowly. If you push the stick to the limit, object moves at maximum speed. If you want this effect (I would), you don't need to normalize speed if it does not exceed the maximum. Also if `moveSquared` is <= 1.0, then the speed will never exceed possible maximum.